# Getting the Outlook Out of Office flag with .NET

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server-2003

My company is using Exchange 2003.

Is it possible to query exchange from .NET code to find out if someone's 'Out of Office' assisstant is on or off?

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) library, you can get Out of Office status like this:

```
public bool IsOutOfOffice()
{
    var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    var rdoSession = new Redemption.RDOSession();
    rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = outlook.Session.MAPIOBJECT;

    Redemption.RDOOutOfOfficeAssistant OOFA = 
        (_rdoSession.Stores.DefaultStore as Redemption.RDOExchangeMailboxStore).OutOfOfficeAssistant

    return OOFA.OutOfOffice;
}
```

To check another user's status, you need to get the `MAPIOBJECT` for their mailbox.

Comment: Do you know an example of how "to get the MAPIOBJECT for their mailbox"