# Getting the Out of Office status programatically from Exchange or AD?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, exchange-server

When people use Outlook (in this case in a Windows AD Domain running Exchange 2003 and 2007), they can set an Out of Office reply. Office Communicator 2005 can access it as well, so I assume there has to be a way to access it programatically?

Does anyone know how to? I assume that Exchange would be the place to ask as AD doesn't seem to know about this.

(Note: This is about getting the OOO Status from e.g., a server process, not from a .net client app running on the users machine, so Office Interop won't work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the Outlook Out of Office flag with .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305322/getting-the-outlook-out-of-office-flag-with-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this [post](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2008/02/class-library-to-help-setting-out-of.html) might be helpful.